# Padding Bottom not working in IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<style>
    body {
        background-color: #e4e4e4;
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
        mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
    }

    .ExternalClass * {
        line-height: 100%;
    }

    .bgimg {
        background-image: url('http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/images/wth_map.jpg');
        width: 100%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 77%; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .checkout-price {
        position: absolute;
        top: 590px;
        margin-left: 25px;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        font: 28px/120px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(black, .3);
        text-indent: -1px;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        background: #e54930;
        border: 1px solid;
        border-color: #b33323  #ab3123  #982b1f;
        border-radius: 60px;
        @include user-select(none);
        @include linear-gradient(top, #f75a3b, #d63b29);
        @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(white, .3), 0 1px 2px rgba(black, .2));
    }

        .checkout-price:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 3px;
            bottom: 3px;
            left: 3px;
            right: 3px;
            border: 2px solid #f5f8fb;
            border-radius: 60px;
            @include box-shadow(inset 0 1px 1px rgba(white, .2), inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(black, .25), 0 -1px 1px rgba(black, .25));
        }

    .cheapest {
        margin-left: 80px;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-top: 22px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
    }

    .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .indsub {
        color: #e62529;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        div, p, a, li, td {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;
        }

            table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {
                width: 300px !important;
            }

        img {
            display: block !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }

        [class].hide {
            display: none !important;
        }

        [class].w100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .cheapest {
            margin-left: 5px;
            font-size: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }

        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .indsub {
            color: #e62529;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .checkout-price {
            margin-left: 0px;
            top: 260px;
        }
        /*.bgimg {
        background-image: url('images/wth_map.jpg');
        width: 100%;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 77%; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }*/
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        div, p, a, li, td {
            /*-webkit-text-size-adjust: none !important;*/
        }

            table[class="table"], td[class="cell"] {
                width: 300px !important;
            }

        img {
            display: block !important;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }

        [class].hide {
            display: none !important;
        }

        [class].w100 {
            width: 100% !important;
            text-align: left !important;
        }

        .cheapest {
            margin-left: 5px;
            font-size: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow',Arial,sans-serif;
            max-width: 100% !important;
        }

        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .indsub {
            color: #e62529;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .checkout-price {
            margin-left: 0px;
            top: 260px;
        }
    }
</style>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<div style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td class="cell">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #666666">If this email doesn't display properly you can view it in your web browser<a href="http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/201401.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;"> Click Here</a></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img src="http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/images/high_quality_logo_wth.png" width="500" height="108" border="0" style="display: block"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table border="0" align="right" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" class="w100">
                                        <!--<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#333333" style="font-size:22px"><strong>WorldTravelHub</strong></font><br>
                  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#666666" style="font-size:18px">Newsletter
                    </font>-->

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="290" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <!--<tr>
                <td class="w100"><div class="left_align" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#666666" style="font-size:12px"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#333333" style="font-size:11px"><strong>We'll get you the CHEAPEST flights to the</strong></font>

<font><span style="color:#ff5313;font-size:29px;">Indian Subcontinent </span></font>
</div>

                </td>
              </tr>-->
                            </table>
                            <table width="290" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <!-- <tr>
                  <td class="w100">
                     <img class="stamp" src="images/stamp.png" alt="CHEAPEST GAURANTEE" />

</td>
                </tr>-->
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!--<img src="images/600.png" border="0" style="display:block">-->
                            <div class="bgimg">


                                <p class="cheapest">
                                    <span class="bold">We'll get you the CHEAPEST flights to the</span><br />
                                    <span class="indsub">Indian Subcontinent</span>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="w100">
                                        <span class="checkout-price">
                                            <span style="font-size: 10px;">FROM</span> $850*
                                           <!--<sup style="font-size:8px;margin-top:5px;">From</sup><sub>$850*</sub>--></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="290" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="w100">
                                        <!--<font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#666666" style="font-size:12px"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#333333" style="font-size:14px"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong></font>-->
                                        <div style="text-align: center; margin-right: 30px;">
                                            <a href="tel:1800 984 045" style="color: #e62529; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Toll Free: 1800 984 045</a><br />
                                            <a href="mailto:info@worldtravel.com.au" style="font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 2px; text-decoration: none; color: #000;">info@worldtravelhub.com.au</a><br />
                                            <a href="http://www.worldtravelhub.com.au/" style="font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: #000;">www.worldtravelhub.com.au</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="white">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="w100">
                                        <p style="text-align: center;">
                                            <span style="font-size: 22px; color: #e62529; letter-spacing: 3px; font-weight: bold;">Book online <span style="color: #000;">24/7 </span>at worldtravelhub.com.au</span><br>
                                            <span style="font-size: 8px;">*A Verifiable written quote from another Australian registered travel businesses must be aproved and fare quoted must be generally avaliable to the public in the market and must be for the same date,seat class,fare category and airline and given to us before we make a booking for the customer.The quote must be for booked fares originating in Australia to Indian subcontinent.Lics No<span style="font-weight: bold;"> 2TA6049</span></span>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#888888">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="290" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="w100"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ffffff" style="font-size: 12px"><strong>WorldTravelHub</strong><br>
                  Suite 4, 2 Kendall St,<br>
                  Harris Park NSW 2150</font></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="290" border="0" align="right" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" class="w100">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" class="w100"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#ffffff" style="font-size: 12px"><strong>Phone:</strong> +61 2 8005 2797<br>
                    <strong>Fax:</strong>+61 2 8005 4237<br>
                    <strong>Email:</strong> info@worldtravelhub.com.au</font></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="font-size: 10px; color: #666666">If this email doesn't display properly you can view it in your web browser<a href="http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/201401.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline; color: blue;"> Click Here</a></span>
                            <br>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My html page works fine in all version of Chrome Browsers and IE 10,But Doesn't seem to work properly in IE 8 and IE 9,The problem is with padding-bottom css in class .bgimg.The Bottom Part of the page goes right below,when I add px instead of % it moves upwards and works but the text below ie contact details in red are no longer visible..Please help
Thanks for help in advanced

you can view it on this link.. 
http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/201401.html

Comment: Please format your code - include only the troubling part, and make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Well, your page doesn't have a DOCTYPE declaration, among many other problems (having a `<head>` and a `<body>` is generally considered useful in HTML documents, for example...) Guessing this may be triggering whatever quirks modes IE 8 and IE 9 drop into without a DOCTYPE? Try your CSS with an HTML document that has a DOCTYPE and looks even vaguely like actual HTML and you might have more success.

Comment: Sorry for Posting such a dumb question..new to html and css..Nways Thank you Matt Gibson for your time and help..after editing the following changes it seems to works in all IE versions..Thank you Sir once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply `display: block;` to any element and after give it `padding-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `padding-bottom` and apply the `height` for the div `bgimg`. Also keep the `background-size:cover` for that.

```
  .bgimg {
    background-image: url('http://worldtravelhub.com.au/newsletter/201401/images/wth_map.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:460px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for your answer but after doing the following changes my page seems to loose its responsive effects don't know why

Comment: is it a responsive site earlier?

Comment: Yes..remember me asking about media queries yesterday??

Answer (score -1):

```
<element style = "padding-bottom: 77%;"> </element>
```

been experience on css trouble like that , and some browser element needs to have their style in HTML, so try something like on the above rather than on css file.